# Computing $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{j = 1}^N \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{j = 1}^N \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}.$$ My attempt was to use a Riemann sum...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}
&= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} (-1)^{i+j} \int_{0}^{1} x^{i+j-1} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} x \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} (-x)^{i-1} \right)^{2} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} x \left( \frac{1- \smash{(-x)^{N}}}{1+x} \right)^{2} \, dx.
\end{align*}

Therefore, taking $N \to \infty$ it follows (from the dominated convergence or any suitable theorem you like), we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{(1+x)^{2}} \, dx
 = \log 2 - \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}